# exception eaccessviolation in module laragon.exe

Tags: php, laravel, laragon

I installed Laragon on Windows 10, on the Laragon administrator account it worked fine, while on the user account there was an error

```
"exception eaccessviolation in module laragon.exe"
```

I have reinstalled and followed several YouTube tutorials but it has not been solved

I hope laragon users can help me